# How to fix 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'Client' in python3?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am running a simple code that utilizes google cloud vision api but it keeps on throwing this error. I have tries upgrading my packages shown here: [How to fix AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client' when running python in Google Cloud Interactive Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362736/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-client-when-runnin) but the error persists.

PS:am using a virtual environment(virtualenv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Client()` class was [removed in the Client Library v0.25.1 and replaced with ImageAnnotatorClient()](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/python-client-migration#create_a_client).

You can either replace `Client` with`ImageAnnotatorClient`, or use a version of the Client Library prior to v0.25.1 by specifying it in the requirements.txt

Comment: Great to know! If you'd be so kind as to mark the answer as accepted so others can see it easily :)